# How can I "play" with QualityCenter OTA API without having a QC server?

Tags: quality-center

I am in the process of developing an application that uses QC OTA API, and although I find OTA API Reference a good place to start, I really need to have a server I could connect to/try things out on.

One solution would be to download the QC ALM evaluation software, but I do not have the hardware for a server nor the patience/time required to get it to work (the steps are described [here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aQGQ_jhSuQUQJ%3ab0mbjack.blogspot.com/2011/04/quality-center-11-on-windows-2008.html%20&cd=7&hl=en&ct=clnk&client=ubuntu)).

Is there such a thing as a public sample QC server?
(Forum systems come to mind, when they let you post in a sample bulletin board, experiment with themes, and it all gets restored the next day)

Is there something I could connect to, and try their API without the hassle of installing QualityCenter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what all the guidelines are, but you could consider becoming an HP partner. I believe you have to pay a small amount, but you get access to all their products for integration purposes. It does run into the same problem as the evaluation software does, but you only need to configure it once, and you get access to their support. My experience with their support for their Silver partners program has been hit or miss in the past. I'd say 1/3 of the time I get a rep who slows things down, but the rest of the time I get a rockstar who wants to actually help.

Since I find it unlikely you'll find a public sandbox for it, I think getting your own server is the best course of action. And since the evaluation software will likely expire after some point, I'd recommend the partner's program.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience with the partner program.  This sounds perfect for someone who is involved in developing a commercial application or can afford it. Unfortunately, I am doing this for myself, as a learning exercise, and was hoping for _"... everything just kind of all-inclusive, free kind of..."_ way to get my hands dirty. :)   I will accept your answer, as this makes perfect sense and is a good advice.

Comment: Oops, I need 15 reputation to up-vote. Will up-vote when I have the chance, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What about running the evaluation version in a virtual environment? Then you wont need dedicated hardware. I've found this works well for developing and testing QC integrations.
You could use an open source virtualisation solution such as [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)

Answer (score 0):

After a long time, a new positive answer:

HPQC 12.20 Community Edition 12.20

is free software ( permanent non-expiring license, 5 users ),

runs well on 
Win8Pro with SQLServerExpress
( so no need for special os or database versions anymore)

and might be permanent playground for anybody interested in scripting via the OTA interface :-), released 2015-01-15.

See my homepage about "HP Quality Center Community Edition"
http://www.hemmerling.com/doku.php/en/alm.html
and OTA
http://www.hemmerling.com/doku.php/en/alm02.html

Comment: What does your home page add, it doesn't really explain much, seems like a bunch of more links? Why not link to the HP download pages directly? http://www8.hp.com/us/en/software-solutions/alm-software-development-testing/try-now.html

Comment: Well.. my homepage tells you the tricks how to install and handle the tool step by step,its not just a link page. A newbie will likely fail with many questions... e.g. how to import demo projects, how to configure SQL server ect.